# Dynamic reading of input file based on DDMMYYYY in java

Tags: java, regex

I've a Folder, where I receive files from someother application and gets stored in the folder. The file format is

> "ABC_DIFL_MMDDYYYYmillisecs.log"

I don't want to pass the file name manually, I want to read the file dynamically based on today's date. What are the possible ways to do this???

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class to take a Date object and format it so it can be used as part of the filename.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
String filename = "ABC_DIFL_" + df.format(new Date()) + ".log";
```

You can read about the format that the SimpleDateFormat on [the API page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You also have the more tricky problem of finding the file that has a millisecond suffix. This could be created from a Date object, which has millisecond precision, but how do you know which millisecond is the right one?

What you need to do is to take the list of files in the directory and test them to find the one that starts with todays date. This can be done as follows:

```
public File findTodaysFirstFile(File directory) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    String prefix = "ABC_DIFL_" + df.format(new Date());

    for (File current : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (current.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
            return current;
        }
    }
    // handle failure here, throw an exception or return null as you prefer
}
```

Comment: You need `dd` there. `DD` gives day in the year. Also, append the extension `.log` as well.

Comment: Oh Sorry, Thanks for the reply, but the date also has millisecs appened to it. I'm editing my question. That's where my confusion was..! Sorry to bother you after you replied.

Comment: And yyyy instead of YYYY.

Comment: Are the milliseconds actually fixed or is it an arbitrary point in the day?

Comment: Its arbitrary. Not fixed, I think we need to use Regex here. And I'm bad at regex. any leads other than regex or should I continue with regex???

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I've no control over the file. It is in shared location and generated by external application. But the good part is it generates only once a day.